# Buttons "Save" and "Cancel" dissapeared after changing Form with InfoPath

Tags: infopath, form

I have a problem with buttons in a Form. Buttons have disappeared after changing the Form in InfoPath, and I do not know how to add them again.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint is this? Was the form already created when you started to change it? Was it custom buttons that disappeared or the ribbon?

Comment: SharePoint 2013. Yes, the form was already created. I am not  strong with termenology, but buttons below the form were disapeared (suppose, yes, custom).

Comment: Do the form got multiple views? Have you closed the form or can you undo any changes that might have removed the buttons using ctrl + z? If the form was not to advanced, my best bet is that you had 2 buttons, one for save and one to cancel?

Comment: By default, there's no versioning on infopath forms, so when any changes to an existing form is published, it is overwritten.

Comment: I just need to create custom view via InfoPath, and after making all changies and publishing the form, buttons "save" and "cancel" disapeared.

Comment: And you are sure that you created/edited the "edit" form? Perhaps you created a display/view form, and in those, buttons are hidden.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not advanced user, I just click in SP Designer on "Design form in InfoPath".

Comment: I understand. If you could use SP designer to navigate to the list where the forms are present, what does it said under "Forms?"

Comment: DispForm.aspx; EditForm.aspx; NewForm.aspx.

Comment: Could this information help you to answer the question?

Comment: Sorry for not coming back to you. It seems that the lists default forms has been modified. Is all the list forms customized in infopath? If you go to the list in SharePoint and click view item, new item and edit item, does the forms all look the same?

Comment: Thank you very much for comming back! Yes, they are the same. May be you could help me, how I could customize a form one more time from the beginnig, but without loosing buttons "Save" and "Cancel"?